# Reading a File, and instantiating an object with properties based on the data read

Tags: java

I am trying to import data from a file and create objects out of it and then store it into an array. I am a beginner and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I recieve 6 errors:

1. .\Employees.java:92: error: class, interface, or enum expected
   }
   ^
2. Employeetest.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
   objectArray[counter] = setFirstName(firstNameEmployee);
3. symbol:   method setFirstName(String)
   location: class Employeetest
   Employeetest.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
   objectArray[counter] = setLastName(lastNameEmployee);
4. symbol:   method setLastName(String)
   location: class Employeetest
   Employeetest.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
   objectArray[counter] = setAge(ageEmployee);
5. symbol:   method setAge(double)
   location: class Employeetest
   Employeetest.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
   objectArray[counter] = setHourlySalary(hourlySalaryEmployee);
6. symbol:   method setHourlySalary(double)
   location: class Employeetest
   Employeetest.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
   objectArray[counter] = setWeeklyHoursWorked(weeklyhoursworkedEmployee);

   symbol:   method setWeeklyHoursWorked(double)
   location: class Employeetest
   6 errors

This is what I have.

```
    This is my objects class 
    public class Employees {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;    
    private double age;
    private double hourlySalary;
    private double weeklyhoursworked;
    private double weeklysalary;

    public void setFirstName(String EmployeeFirstName) {
        firstName = EmployeeFirstName;
        return;
    } 
    public void setLastName(String EmployeeLastName){
        lastName = EmployeeLastName;
        return;
   }
   public void setAge(double EmployeeAge){
        age = EmployeeAge;
        return;
   }
    public void setHourlySalary(double EmployeeHourlySalay){
        hourlySalary = EmployeeHourlySalay;
        calculateWeeklySalary(weeklyhoursworked);
        return;
    }
    public void setWeeklyHoursWorked(double EmployeeWeeklyHoursWorked){
        weeklyhoursworked = EmployeeWeeklyHoursWorked;
        return;
    }
    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }
    public double getAge(){
        return age;
    }
    public double getHourlySalary(){
        return hourlySalary;
    }
    public double getWeeklyHourlyWorked(){
        return weeklyhoursworked;
   }
    public double getWeeklySalary(){
        return weeklysalary;
    }
    public void calculateWeeklySalary(double hoursWorked) {
    weeklysalary = (hoursWorked * hourlySalary);
    return;
    }
    }
```

This is my main program where I am trying to import the data, convert it to an object, then it store it as an array.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Employeetest
{


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

String firstNameEmployee = "null";
String lastNameEmployee = "null";   
double ageEmployee;
double hourlySalaryEmployee;
double weeklyhoursworkedEmployee;
double weeklySalaryEarnedEmployee;
int counter = 0;

Employees objectArray[] = new Employees[counter + 1]; 
FileReader fr = new FileReader("Employeedata.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

counter = 0;
while ((firstNameEmployee = br.readLine()) != null) {
    objectArray[counter] = setFirstName(firstNameEmployee);
    lastNameEmployee = br.readLine();
    objectArray[counter] = setLastName(lastNameEmployee);
    ageEmployee = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    objectArray[counter] = setAge(ageEmployee);
    hourlySalaryEmployee = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    objectArray[counter] = setHourlySalary(hourlySalaryEmployee);
    weeklyhoursworkedEmployee = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    objectArray[counter] = setWeeklyHoursWorked(weeklyhoursworkedEmployee);
    System.out.println(objectArray[counter]);
counter++;
}
    br.close();     
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Unidentifiable Error, Anything noticeable?

Comment: 4 spaces before each line to make it into a code segment. It makes the code easier to read

Comment: More importantly, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Your code is not at all clear. Can you indent it.

Comment: This is the error I get and I will edit this post to make my code more clear. Employeetest.java:83: error: class, interface, or enum expected
} 
^
1 error

Comment: Go to line 83 of Employeetest.java and you'll find the issue. You haven't shown us that bit of code. And that error is far from "unidentifiable".

Comment: `objectArray[counter] = setFirstName(firstNameEmployee);` setFirstName is defined as a method - first create an instance of that class, and then call the method on that instance. Further, the set* methods are void and do not return anything. eg `Employee e = new Employee(); e.setFirstName(...)`

Comment: Instead of writing an entire read-write system, why not just use Gson to serialise the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem

You are calling methods that cannot be accessed without accessing the object first..

Moving On:

```
while ((firstNameEmployee = br.readLine()) != null) {
    objectArray[counter] = setFirstName(firstNameEmployee);
    lastNameEmployee = br.readLine();
    objectArray[counter] = setLastName(lastNameEmployee);
    ageEmployee = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    objectArray[counter] = setAge(ageEmployee);
    hourlySalaryEmployee = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    objectArray[counter] = setHourlySalary(hourlySalaryEmployee);
    weeklyhoursworkedEmployee = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    objectArray[counter] = setWeeklyHoursWorked(weeklyhoursworkedEmployee);
    System.out.println(objectArray[counter]);
counter++;
}
```

We are going to take a look at this code block.
First, you read a value from the file and assign it to a variable. Then, you assigned it to the object... Which is where the problem becomes apparent

This is what you have

```
objectArray[counter] = setLastName(lastNameEmployee);
```

To Fix just change all the lines that have methods like the above to this

```
objectArray[counter].setLastName(lastNameEmployee);
```

Another Example

Instead of

```
 objectArray[counter] = setAge(ageEmployee);
```

do

```
 objectArray[counter].setAge(ageEmployee);
```

**To Fix the Null Pointer Exception**

```
for(int x =0; x< objectArray.length;x++)
{
    objectArray[x] = new Employees();
}
```

Put that loop right under

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

The reason is because objects in an object array are null at first. Thus, you need to instantiate them before u can mutate their instance variables.

Comment: I see thanks, I still get one error.                                       .\Employees.java:92: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
1 error

Comment: Is it me or does your array have the size of 1 because your counter is =0

Comment: Which line is 92 ?

Comment: My apologies I had an extra bracket in the object class I didn't see. Any idea what would cause this error?                                                       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Employeetest.main(Employeetest.java:24)

Comment: Which line is line 24

Comment: Line 24: objectArray[counter].setFirstName(firstNameEmployee);

Comment: The problem is all objects are instantiated as null in the array

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate everyone's help

Comment: No problem. All and all we fixed all those errors ^_^